# "change connection string in stimulsoft in run time dos not work"

Tags: stimulsoft

//hi every one i am beginner in stimullsoft   this is my code for change connection string //in stimullsoft   2012 in run time but it dos not return any things please help me

```
rpt_nogoresd_bij.Dictionary.Databases.Clear();    
rpt_nogoresd_bij.Dictionary.Databases.Add(new  Stimulsoft.Report.Dictionary.StiSqlDatabase("mashaghel", str_connect ));

rpt_nogoresd_bij.Dictionary.Variables["date"].Value = txt_date.Text;
rpt_nogoresd_bij.Dictionary.Variables["azhozeh"].Value = "220111";
rpt_nogoresd_bij.Dictionary.Variables["tahozeh"].Value = "220623";
rpt_nogoresd_bij.Dictionary.Variables["sal"].Value = "1391";        
rpt_nogoresd_bij.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

please declare you variables type, ex: `int - char and ...`
and You have not saved the report templates.

Add the `rpt_nogoresd_bij.Save()` method.